# Fix grub.cfg to boot ubuntu

Tags: grub2

I screwed up the grub.cfg file in ubuntu and now i cant boot to that partition. What do i need to put in the file to be able to boot from that partition?

Comment: What version of grub are you using?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using grub2 you can just run a `sudo update-grub` to find the correct OSes and generate a new cfg.

From a live CD, you'll have to mount your partition:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/root
sudo mount -t ext3 <your ubuntu partition, example /dev/sda4> /mnt/root
sudo mount -t proc none /mnt/root/proc
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/root/sys
sudo chroot /mnt/root /bin/bash
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: so i'm using grub2. but i'm in a live cd at the moment.

Comment: Result: Sudo: update-grub: command not found

Comment: @user1450296: that makes no sense. Conner is perfectly right. He explained all the steps to get into the system from a live CD or an ordinary boot CD. Grub2 wouldn't be installed without also having `update-grub`.

Comment: hi! is there anything to do if after performing update-grub, the problem isn't fixed? for me, I do it from an Ubuntu partition (I use dual-boot system on the same hard disk)

Comment: @user1450296 See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/418666/update-grub-command-not-found

Comment: From Live session, I get an error about the canonical path of /cow.