# update-grub command not found

Tags: grub2

I'm trying to update my grub config on ubuntu server 12.04.3 to include the `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` variable as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2.

The procedure says run `update-grub` after making the change but it's doesn't appear to be on my system. How can I install this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would reinstall grub by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub
```

Comment: i lost update-grub after a do-release-upgrade. This worked for me.

Comment: I also did do_release_upgrade but don't know if I lost it after that. if I run the above command, this is what I get: 
`Package grub is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  grub2-common`

Comment: Saved my life thrice, only solution that worked in `chroot` for me

Answer (score 36):

The `update-grub` command was created to make things easier - it is simply a shell script in `/usr/sbin/`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"
```

If it is not there, you can make your own. To do that, run this, and paste in the above script:

```
sudo nano /usr/sbin/update-grub
```

Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then run these:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/sbin/update-grub
sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/update-grub
```

And you should now be able to run `update-grub`. :-)

Comment: Thanks, since it was missing I reinstalled grub. Not sure if anything else might of went missing.

Comment: This is a lifesaver if reinstalling grub is not an option because of a broken system.

Comment: Yes, really, lifesaver. The update-grub command was on my system, but gave me a /cow error, this one gave no error output.

Comment: Do you know how to regenerate grub.cfg from a live session?

Comment: @Quidam https://askubuntu.com/q/145241/178596. Also tools such as Boot Repair *AFAIK* can do it sort of. Recovery Mode if you can access that is also an option (Dropping to a root shell prompt which can run commands after mounting partitons)

Comment: Boot repair didn't. I tried many things from your link it seems, and got the /cow canonical path error. Looks like my system is messed up, I think the only option is a boot  repairing live cd.

Answer (score 3):

you need to run it with root priviledges, run: `sudo update-grub`. Unless you removed it, its there in the system.

Comment: It was definitely gone, not sure how it went missing. Re-install grub brought it back.

Comment: It is NOT there on some Linux releases such as Fedora 31.  Granted the question specifies Ubuntu but your answer could cover other releases using Grub.

Answer (score 2):

If `sudo update-grub` doesn't work for you,

Try this

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

It will make grub entry for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is supplemental to Sajith Sajan's answer:

Take a look in `/usr/sbin` and `/boot`. You may need to run:

`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the following error:

```
$ sudo update-grub
sudo update-grub: command not found
```

That is caused by copying and pasting from the Ubuntu wiki not working. It turns the space into an invisible character. **You have to manually type over the command to make it work.**

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I was the root user, at the time I attempted to run `update-grub`. When `exit` to my regular user account `sudo update-grub` works without error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/418674/265303) to do `sudo apt-get update`, but I get lock held by `packagekitd` process error with pid, even reboot still same.

I use `ps alxww --forest` to confirm pid of `packagekitd`. Then `sudo strace -f -s 100 -p <PID>` to attach pid to `strace` to see what's going on.

The log shows 2 paths get downloading, one of them is `'/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/tw.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_Contents-amd64.gz'`.

Simply use `sudo watch ls -lathi '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/'` to watch the progress until it's done. Now `sudo apt update` is working. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub` shows `Package grub is not available`. But try again with `sudo grub-update`, the command is come back.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `update-grub` script exists in another directory (eg. `/usr/sbin`) but that directory (`/usr/sbin`) is not on your system path.

If this is the case, you could run the script by specifying the exact path, eg. `/usr/sbin/update-grub`. However, to avoid another "command not found" error for `grub-mkconfig`, a better option would be to add the missing directory to the system path like this:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
update-grub
```

This will let your system look up the `/usr/sbin` directory for `update-grub` as well as other executables in that directory.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to terminal and StackExchange, but I found a way around to **update-grub command not found **

:sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub

I used the above command to reinstall GRUB, but it gave me

Package grub is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
grub2-common:i386 grub-efi-amd64:i386 grub2-common grub-pc grub-efi-ia32
grub-efi-amd64

So i tried to reinstall above packages with
:sudo apt-get install --reinstall (ABOVE 6 PACKAGES)
EX: :sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub2-common

Then I used  :sudo update-grub to update it, and it worked displaying

**Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done**

then i used the following

:sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64:

:sudo update-grub:

:sudo grub-install:

Reboot and use the following

:sudo update-grub:

Comment: POP OS is off-topic at this site.