# Kernel Update from 4.2.0-30-generic to 4.4

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, kernel, updates

I recently created a partition on my Macbook Pro (late 2013 release) to run Ubuntu, following [this tutorial](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/materials/pdfs/How_to_Dual-Boot_OSX_and_Ubuntu.pdf).

I managed to have it running smoothly, but I need to update the Kernel to 4.4.  I've been following [this website's instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-4-in-ubuntu/) but once I reboot my computer and log back in and run `uname -r`, the Kernel is still `4.2.0-30-generic`. I've also tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to see GRUB, but the apparently installed Kernel 4.4 doesn't appear on the list.

Any ideas?

**UPADTE 1:**

After Hyltixa helped me, it seems that GRUB is the problem here. After running `sudo update-grub` this shows up:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
Found Mac OS X on /dev/sda5
done
```

which shows that the files did in fact get installed. But GRUB is not showing them as options when booting

**UPDATE 2**

Here's a snapshot of the grub-customizer tool:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it should work any different for Ubuntu users than Elementary OS, but to upgrade from 4.2 (or whatever kernel) to the released "LTS" version of 4.4, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Use : `apt-cache search linux|grep xenial` to check what is available. If nothing is found, you have to select the correct sources for your distro :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that /boot/grub/grub.cfg did not have the proper kernel list in it... after some more searching, the second answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418666/update-grub-command-not-found) worked for me:

`sudo exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Answer (score -1):

I did that on my elementaryOS and it worked fine! Just make sure you get the right files when you download them, AND you install them in this order.

linux-headers-4.4.0-xxx_all.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-xxx-generic_xxx_i386/amd64.deb
linux-image-4.4.0-xxx-generic_xxx_i386/amd64.deb

Comment: Thanks Hyltixa, I did it exactly as in the website for the 64-bit, line by line, but the kernel just won't update :'(

Comment: Do you use the software app to start the 3 debfiles or terminal ?

Comment: I used the terminal. Give me a minute, I will send you my ID in a sec

Comment: Great, trying to fix my teamviewer to! :)

Comment: Hi again! 

Try using the grub-customizer according to the answer to this question you find here, there you can easy modife grub and the order in grub, try to see with this app if you can make any changes to the grub to make the 4,4 kernel to show up as boot alternativ !

http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Comment: I tried the software without luck. My bet is that the Boot loader (if you look into the second to last page of the tutorial I provided a link to) is keeping me from being able to see the 4.4

Comment: Yes but in grub-customizer you can organize all available boot options. Does the kernels lists in grub-customizer ?

Comment: Yes, let me put a picture up