# Is there a way to configure Dual Boot after Windows installation in a separate drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, windows, ssd

**Context**: I have a notebook which originally had an SSD and an HDD. For very specific reasons, at some point, I had two ubuntus, one in which drive, until recently I changed the HDD for another SSD (in which I installed Windows 11).

**Current situation**: My notebook has ubuntu 22.04 in one SSD and Windows 11 in the other one.

**Problem**: Ubuntu's dual boot configuration is set to the situation described in **Context**, so, when I boot, I get the option to boot ubuntu that is currently in my SSD and an ubuntu that no longer exists.

Is there a way to reconfigure the dual boot so that I can choose between ubuntu and Windows without having to install ubuntu 22.04 again?

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`, and add the line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`.

Then, run the command `sudo update-grub`, and reboot.

Comment: The command `sudo  update-grub` was not available. Alternatively used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418666/update-grub-command-not-found) and it worked either way. Thank you.